# Angular 2 Jasmine tests for an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am testing a component that calls a service. I want to stub or mock the service so that it returns a Boolean value and my component variables that are in the callback/ success function of the subscribe function are set to this mocked Boolean. So in my component calls a method getBusinessDetails in welcomeService from my component, this is where I am having the issue. I want the isReturning value to be faked and then set the corresponding component variables. It returns Expecte dundefined to be true.

```
 public getBusinessDetails(): void {
        this.welcomeService.getBusiness(this.businessId, 2017)
            .subscribe((isReturning) => {
                this.isReturningApplicant = isReturning;
                this.welcomeMessage = this.isReturningApplicant ? 'Welcome Back' : 'Welcome';
            });
    }


TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [WelcomeComponent],
            imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
            providers: [{ provide: SessionService, useValue: sessionServiceStub },
            { provide: WelcomeService, useValue: welcomeServiceStub }]
        });

describe('Gets  details', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            sessionServiceStub = {
                getSession: function () { return { businessId: 11111, agentId: 11111 } }
            }
            welcomeServiceStub = {
                getBusiness: function () { return { subscribe: () => Observable.of(true) } }
            };
        })

        it('get a returning customer', () => {
            component.ngOnInit();
            expect(component.isReturningApplicant).toBe(true);

        });

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it return the observable without `subscribe`

```
getBusiness: function () { return Observable.of(true) }
```

the `Observable` returned has the `subscribe` method

```
getBusiness().subscribe()
```

the `getBusiness` returns the `Observable` and then you change the call to the `Observable.subscribe`

Comment: Super, your a lifesaver and a genius !

Comment: if i have a suite describes that are changing the values, ie setting the variable to false, would this cause an issue ?@peeskillet

Comment: Not really sure what you mean

Comment: In the before each I am changing the value of the variable, if i have another describe with the before each setting a different value, i noticed this has an impact. Is this because the tests are running async ?

Comment: Might better to just use a spy and spy on the method and return the Observable fro the spy

Comment: Do I spy on the welcomeServiceStub ? spyOn(welcomeServiceStub, 'getBusiness').and.returnValue(true); @peeskillet

Comment: Get it from the injector. `TestBed.get(MyService)`.  The do `spyOn(myService, 'getSomehing').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true))`. I've ran into cases where spying on the stub directly wouldn't work